# Camel aggregation with REST routes

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, integration

I have a Camel application and I'm trying to do some aggregation based on some outputs from different responses (REST Web services).

This is what I have so far (the Camel routes):

```
@Component
public final class AggregationRoute extends RouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    rest("/aggregation")
        .get()
        .to("direct:retrieve");

    from("direct:retrieve")
        .multicast(/*new BodyAggregationStrategy(), true*/)
        .to("direct:foo")
        .to("direct:foo1");

    from("direct:foo")
        .to("seda:http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php?sector=conus")
        .to("direct:aggregate");

    from("direct:foo1")
        .to("seda:http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php?sector=conus")
        .to("direct:aggregate");

    from("direct:aggregate")
        .aggregate(header("id"), new BodyAggregationStrategy())
        .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, simple("${body}").getText());
  }
}
```

...the "aggregation strategy"

```
public final class BodyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
  @Override
  public Exchange aggregate(final Exchange oldExchange, final Exchange newExchange) {
    if (null == oldExchange) {
      return newExchange;
    }

    String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

    oldExchange.getIn().setBody(oldBody + "+" + newBody);
    return oldExchange;
  }
}
```

...eventually, the Web services are going to be different, but I'm just trying now to see if I can solve this basic trouble first.

I defined a REST endpoint, when `GET /aggregation` is hit (on *my side*), I want to consult two or more REST Web services and aggregate the response from those; then "answer" back.

Any clues?

Comment: Take a look at the Scatter-Gather pattern https://camel.apache.org/scatter-gather.html

Comment: I agree with both @Itsallas & Claus , if your rest calls are going to be sequential then consider storing each of the responses in a header/property and then aggregate the values using a simple processor.

Answer (score 3):

The multicast EIP has built-in aggregator, so configure the aggregation strategy on this pattern, instead of using a separate aggregator. This ensures the messages are mutlicasted and aggregate as part of the same *unit of work* and the result can be visible and send back to the calling REST client.